# Gulp watch don't include hidden folders (with dot)

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have structure:

> -/app/.default/style.sass
>
> -/app/another_folder/style.sass
>
> -glpfile.js

and gulp task

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./app/**/*.sass', gulp.parallel('sass'));
    gulp.watch('./app/**/*.js', gulp.parallel('js'));
});
```

Why **gulp watch** don't see change in **.default** folder?

p.s.:
Sorry me on my english.

Answer (score 0):

To get `watch` to work I had to explicitly set the "dotFolder" like this:

```js
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['./app/**/*.sass', './app/.**/*.sass'], gulp.parallel(sass));
    gulp.watch('./app/**/*.js', gulp.parallel('js'));
});
```

Note the extra entry in the `watch` task:

`'./app/.**/*.sass'`  // that is the only way I could get it to work.

Gulp has a `dot` option for `gulp.src` but not for `gulp.watch`.

You will have to use that dot option in your `gulp.src`'s,  like:

`gulp.src('./app/**/*.sss', { dot: true })`

The issue is here, see https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2385 but closed without help.

Comment: I tested it.  Did you also put the `{ dot: true }` in your `gulp.src`'s?  Edit your question to show the changes you have made to the `watch` and `sass` tasks.